# How can I make a panel control appear underneath all other controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

I have problems with a panel control in my WinForms application. How to make it so its under everything else? Right now the text is under the panel.

Comment: right click it and "Send to Back" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the design view, select the panel and then click on the "Send to Back" option in the toolbar or on the context menu.

[image: Send To Back on the Toolbar]

[image: Send to Back on the Context Menu]

What this does is change the order the controls are added to the form.

If I have three controls, a `CheckBox`, `Label` and `Button` I see this code in the .designer.cs file:

```
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
```

Sending the `CheckBox` to the back reorders the list so that it is added last.

```
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
```

Therefore the controls in the `ControlCollection` must be drawn in reverse order as the ones at the end are the ones at the back and have to be drawn first so that they can be properly obscured by the ones in front.

Comment: Note that you can also do this at run-time using the [`SendToBack` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback.aspx) of the `Control` class.

Answer (score 0):

try to use: `textBox1.SendToBack();`